# What's the correct URI for a PUT REST request?

Tags: rest

What's the correct URI for a PUT REST request if i want to edit/update only one article?

Is it:

```
// PUT api/articles
```

or:

```
// PUT api/articles/id
```

**UPDATE**

I don't know if i can send the article id from the body with all other attributes (title, etc.) and emit the id from the URI or should i add it to the URI as well. But i guess that i got my answer already. Will have the id in the body and URI i guess.

Comment: A PUT request where? How is the endpoint defined? Either is 'valid' depending on how the corresponding endpoint is written.

Comment: @Andonaeus Is there no general rule for how the URI should look like for this?

Comment: @Evert 's comment gives an example of a general rule of thumb. But, again, it is entirely dependent on the situation. Do you have to provide an id when creating an article, or will one be automatically generated? If it's generated, then you wouldn't want to add /id . In this case, it might make sense to just PUT against api/articles. If you're updating, you can add a /id .

Comment: @Andonaeus i need it for an update operation. I want to update/edit an article. But i just didn't knew if i could send the id from the body with the all other attributes an emit the id from the URI or if i should add it to the URI as well. But i guess that i got my answer already. Will have the id in the body and URI i guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you are saying, I'm guessing you want to update or create a new article, not replace *all* articles.

`PUT` is used to replace the resource that you are targeting. This means that:

```
PUT api/articles
```

creates or replaces all your articles, and:

```
PUT api/articles/id
```

Creates or replaces the article 'id'.

Comment: I though that it was done this way, just wasn't sure. Thank you for confirming it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're following REST principles, then the correct answer is, "Whatever you got back in the Location header from the POST request that created the resource". The basic idea is that the server assigns a URI path as the resource identifier when the resource is created. That path is what you then use in subsequent requests, including GET, PUT and DELETE, when you want to refer to the same resource.

If the resource you want to update is retrieved by doing a GET to /api/articles, then use /api/articles for your PUT request too. If you GET /api/articles/id, then use PUT /api/articles/id to make changes to it.